# Passing var or const to a function

Tags: variables, symbols, eval

I have a function called `put-docstr` that takes a string.  I can set the string using
`defvar` or `defconst`.  Not sure if I should quote the symbol when using it.

Thus like this

```
(put-docstr #'typex-inhibit-startup-windows 'docstr)
```

or like this

```
(put-docstr #'typex-inhibit-startup-windows docstr)
```

Here is the code

```
(defun put-docstr (fun str)
  "Store string in documentation property.
      (put fun 'function-documentation str)))

(defconst docstr
  "Inhibits emacs startup windows.")

(defun typex-inhibit-startup-windows ()
   (setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
   (add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
      (lambda () (delete-other-windows)) t) )

(put-docstr #'typex-inhibit-startup-windows docstr)
```

Comment: Have you tried it both ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what you want to do.

- Do you want to pass the variable itself - a *symbol*?
- Do you want to pass its *value*?

To pass the symbol, quote it. To pass the value, don't quote it.

- When you quote something, evaluation returns that something (that is, the result of evaluating the quotation).
- When you don't quote something, evaluation returns the result of evaluating that something.

---

A `defconst` is the same as a `defvar`.  The only difference is for us humans: `defconst` is an indication *to us* that the intention is that neither programmers nor code will change the constant's (variable's) value.

Comment: I do not know what is best, about using value or symbol.  For this case, I just fill the docstring.  What changes would be needed for using value or symbol?  I suppose that I cannot use both, but either one or the other.

Comment: It looks like you're using the variable only for its value - you want to pass its value to `putdocstr`, no? Function `putdocstr` doesn't want a symbol/variable as its `STR` arg. (In fact, with just the code you show there's no need for the variable/constant at all - just pass the string. But you may want the variable for some other use, elsewhere.)